# How to Convert wsdl to java classes using apache axis

Tags: apex, soap-api

Help me out to generate java classes from enterprise wsdl.

I followed this link: http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/scala/creating-java-classes-wsdl-file-using-apache-axis-2

I installed apache axis and placed wsdl file in the bin\ directory of AXIS.
downloaded few jars and placed in lib/ and SET the environment variables like JAVA_HOME, PATH and CLASSPATH

> CLASSPATH:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\mail-1.4;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\activation-1.1;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\log4j-1.2.15;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\axis2-ant-plugin-1.6.2;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\saaj;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\commons-discovery;D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\lib\jaxrpc
>
> AXISLIB:%AXIS_HOME%\lib
>
> AXISCLASSPATH:%AXIS_LIB%\axis.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\commons-discovery.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\jaxrpc.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\saaj.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\log4j-1.2.15.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\xml-apis.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\xercesImpl.jar

When I run in command prompt:

```
D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin> wsdl2java.bat -uri D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin\enterprise.wsdl
```

I got below error,I didnt find any new folder with java classes in src/ folder.

> Using AXIS2_HOME: D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2 Using JAVA_HOME:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09 Retrieving document at
>   'D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin\enterprise.wsdl'. Exception in
>   thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException :
>   Error parsing WSDL at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerat
>   ionEngine.java:178) at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35) at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24) Caused by:
>   javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unabl
>   e to resolve imported document at
>   'D:\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2\bin\enterprise .wsdl'.:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found:
>   file:/D:/axis2-
>   1.6.2-bin/axis2-1.6.2/bin/enterprise.wsdl at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source) at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.readInTheWSDLFile(
>   CodeGenerationEngine.java:320) at
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerat
>   ionEngine.java:133) ... 2 more Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/D:/axis
>   2-1.6.2-bin/axis2-1.6.2/bin/enterprise.wsdl at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
>   ... 6 more

Comment: You're executing from the bin directory, you don't need to specify a location,  just use -uri enterprise.wsdl . Also do you need to specify the output dir ? or does it default to something.

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason why you are not using the excellent Salesforce WSC library, http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/? It has all this prebuilt for you and some added features. It also does not require Axis runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way to do the same is using Java EE eclipse Ide.

1. Create a Java Project
2. Include the WSDL file in the project
3. Right Click >> Webservices >> Generate Client

Answer (score 1):

As stupid as it sounds - have you made any typos in the filename?

I didn't specify full path and it works like charm for me:

```
c:\(my user)\axis\bin>wsdl2java -uri enterprise.xml

Using AXIS2_HOME:   c:\(my user)\axis
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Retrieving document at 'enterprise.xml'.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.
WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

But the moment I'll specify incorrect file name (say `enterprise.wsdl` in my case) it throws same error as yours...